# Exclude Certain characters from Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the below regex and I'm having difficultly excluding certain characters. I want to exclude `£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ` from the string.

```
\S*(?=\S{7,30})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*
```

I've tried the below with no luck:

```
/\S*(?=\S{7,30})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=[^£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ])\S*/
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be trying to match strings that have no specified letters. You need to anchor your look-aheads, only that way you can achieve what you need.

```
^(?!\S*[£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ])(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)\S{7,30}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rT2lF0/2)

All the lookaheads check the string at the beginning, and the length check can be moved to the end. You need both `^` and `$` anchors to enable length checking.

If you are matching *words* inside larger string, you [can replace `^` and `$` with word boundary `\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rT2lF0/3):

```
\b(?!\S*[£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ])(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)\S{7,30}\b
```

Or lookarounds (if these are not words, but some symbol sequences):

```
(?<!\S)(?!\S*[£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ])(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)\S{7,30}(?!\S)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rT2lF0/5)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches those characters because `\S` matches any character except whitespace. You only need to exclude those characters as well.

- `[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). It matches any character except whitespace or the ones you don't want.

Just replace every occurence of `\S` in your pattern:

```
[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]*(?=[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]{7,30})(?=[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]*[a-z])(?=[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]*[A-Z])(?=[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]*[\d])[^\s£%&+¬¦éúíóáÉÚÍÓÁ]*
```

Now, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that pattern. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're trying to match in order to improve it a bit.